# Open Display & Brightness Settings on AlertView button

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios9, xcode7

Is there a way to open the Settings in Display&Brightness when tapping an alertView buttons? I want the user to be redirected here in order to change its Standard/Zoom view mode.

Comment: there is a few solutions, but they won't pass the review procedure at all as those are not supported APIs and might violate the Review Guideline.

Comment: Tinder does it, Facebook does it...

Comment: Can you give me steps to re-generate this on Tinder and FB application?

Comment: Install Tinder, disable location. Open Tinder with location disabled and then an alert message will appear and the tap will direct to Settings > Privacy > Location Services

Comment: you are talking about __1.__ location services, __2.__ the Tinder does not open the Settings at all, it shows a static information screen only about where the user _could_ change the settings in the Settings application; but the user needs to navigate there manually.

Comment: You are wrong. I tested many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In iOS 8, there is no supported method for a third-party app to open **Settings**  to anything other than the top level, or to their app's custom settings, if they exist.

What you see in Tinder and Facebook are **system alerts** that iOS presents when your app wants to use the network or location services and (cellular data or) wi-fi is turned off.  This is managed by iOS, and is not something that Tinder or Facebook had to add to their app.

Comment: I implemented the code that redirect to the app's custom settings. But for instance, I want to redirect to the top level Settings. Can this be done? thanks!

Comment: No.  If your app has a Settings bundle, it will always open the app's custom settings.